# Opencv imshow does not create window

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have recently installed opencv 2.4.9 and python on raspberry pi with Debian OS. I have written following simple code to display image

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


print "hello"
cv2.namedWindow("show",0)
print "hello1"
# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)

print "hellp"
cv2.imshow("show",img)
cv2.waitKey(100)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using python 2 IDLE. When I run the program only hello is printed. Also "show" window is not created. I have already tried other answers like "adding waitKey() or creating window. However none worked in my case

I am very new to Raspberry and python. may I know what is wrong in above code?
Also why "hello1" is not printed ?

**EDIT*

As imshow method was not working, I tried matplotlib. However, now window frame is not getting updated

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print "new frame"
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #cv2.imwrite("framenew.jpg",frame)

    # Display the resulting frame
    plt.imshow(gray,cmap ='gray')
    plt.show()

    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

May I know how to correctly use this library

Comment: Try using `cv2.waitKey(0)`, it can explain the not showing image

Comment: if you are using 64 bit machine you have to use `k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF` as stated in the documentation `If you are using a 64-bit machine, you will have to modify k = cv2.waitKey(0) line as follows : k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF`

Comment: and  most of the new raspberry oi are 64 bit ones so I think this might be the problem, see if above fix helps this

Comment: Hi. I tried above solution. Still, neither window is created nor hello1 is printed

Comment: is any output to display images connected to your rpi ? if not then this wont work

Comment: @warl0ck The code in question doesn't do anything with the result of `cv2.waitKey` -- it's irrelevant in this case. As such, I'm not sure what your first 2 comments are intending to solve.

Comment: As OP mentioned that window is not showing, in my case i experienced that if I am not adding `waitKey(0) & 0xFF` then the problem occurs and as I add this line on my machine it works fine

Comment: Am using vncserver. Is this creating problem ??

Comment: `vncserver` should not be the root cause. See my answer below.

Comment: Have you tried calling cv2.namedWindow(...) prior to calling cv2.imshow?

Comment: Yes.Tried that.. it does not help

Answer (score 3):

You may set the key waiting time to `0` second as `waitKey(0)`. Your code `waitKey(100)` instructs OpenCV to wait for 100 milliseconds then destroy the window. If you set `waitKey(5000)` for 5 seconds, it will show the image for 5 seconds and destroy it.

Below is the relevant [OpenCV Doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey).

> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when
>   delay <= 0 ) or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive.
>   Since the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the
>   function will not wait exactly delay ms, it will wait at least delay
>   ms, depending on what else is running on your computer at that time.
>   It returns the code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed
>   before the specified time had elapsed.

Below is a sample usage of the waitKey() that will wait forever for <kbd>Q</kbd> being pressed before destroy the `imshow()` window.

```
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

To show and update your OpenCV Window, only change this line in your update code:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break
```